# Post Authentication custom response to client from Cognito

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

We have lambda triggers set up in Cognito for Pre-Authentication/Post-Authentication, and Post Confirmation.
In all the triggers we are checking against our DynamoDB in order to proceed and the db entries are coming properly as expected.
However, we also want to send some details from our database back to the client at the time of login.
In this case, it's a user object containing our DynamoDB user's uuid.

Our iOS developer is using `AWSAuthUIViewController` and is expecting to access our custom response here:

```
AWSAuthUIViewController
.presentViewController(with: self.navigationController!,
              configuration: config,
          completionHandler: { (provider: AWSSignInProvider, error: Error?) in
                                 //...

                                 let user = AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProvider
                                           .sharedInstance()
                                           .getUserPool()
                                           .currentUser()

                                           /*
                                              do something to access custom 
                                              response of user object
                                            */
})
```

We've looked at [Custom Message Lambda Trigger documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-custom-message.html) but this one relates to MFA so it's not what we're looking for.

The main question is how to have Cognito respond to the client with a custom object containing entries from our DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

A better flow to use is probably the [Custom Authentication Flow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-authentication-flow.html#amazon-cognito-user-pools-custom-authentication-flow). It is not supported in the AWSAuthUIViewController, but you may use the AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool to perform the flow. The custom challenge could be leveraged to pass information back to the client before ending the flow.